# Project Explorer for Python in Ubuntu 16

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, project-management

What are the project explorers or IDEs available for python programmer in Ubuntu?
I am aware about Eclipse and Pydev plugin, but I find it pretty slow. I then usually use Sublime text editor, but that hardly solves purpose.

My typical task involves getting the repository from Github/Bitbucket and understanding the code flow, learning the project. So I would like to have a project explorer which will jump to definition of function, list all occurrences of word, find the calls to function. I would like to have this at project level than just file level. That is, the jump to function should happen even if the function is defined in other file.

The debugging, stepping through each line of code would be a big plus.

Just to give some idea - I use Microsoft Visual Studio (for C++) at work and I a big fan of it. Its a solid IDE with exceptional programmer friendly features.
So is there anything close to it for Python in Ubuntu?

Comment: There's [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), maybe that's an option ?

Comment: @JonasCz thanks, I am looking at what does it provide. Is this a lightweight  IDE? I assume Eclipse as way to heavy.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it to be to be "lightweight", although in my experience, it's faster than Eclipse. It's got tons of features though, and does everything you asked for.

Comment: @JonasCz thanks, I have downloaded it. I will install and give it a try.

Comment: Any plain text editor with Python syntax highlighting, and the ability to configure Tab as four spaces. Compared to simple text editors, PyCharm is an elaborate IDE at the other end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

My vote goes to **PyCharm**.

It is really a good IDE for python users. It integrates well with existing projects as well as new projects. It has all the features that anybody would want.

The quick highlights for those who haven't yet used:-

1. **Autocomplete** - Most of the ide/editor provide this. The good is that it does not only suggest the literals existing in current file. It suggests the methods those can be used on that object.
   For example if you create a `list` - `a = []`; on pressing `a(dot)`, it will suggest `append()` etc.
   It suggests whatever can be used at particular position of caret by pressing `ctrl + space`
2. **Syntax Highlighting** - This is done by all editors. Here the colors can be customized.
3. **Code Flow Understanding** - It jumps to definition, declaration, all places from where particular method is called, all occurrences of a literal - just with keyboard shortcuts.
4. **Coding Guidelines** - It warns you if you are missing some coding guideline.
   For example- naming a function as `HelloWorld()` will result in warning "function name should be lower case"
5. **External Dependencies** - I found this very useful. I can see what all modules I can use, what all functions are there and how their implementation is.
6. **Debugging** - I have not yet done debugging as of now, but I am sure this will also be great looking at the other features that are provided.
7. **Version Control System** - I am yet to use this, but it has VCS.
8. **Themes, Fonts, Color** - We can change the ide theme, its color, font style, font size etc.
9. There are many small fetures like distraction free mode, presentation mode, code refactoring, file structure
10. **Code Inspection** - The best feature I might say. It checks every line of code in all files of project and suggests the coding guideline and its actually intelligent. Try this yourself.

P.S.: After the comment from @JonasCz, I installed and used PyCharm. Thanks.